# Can I buy more free tier hours for Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have a bunch of applications that run on the free tier and are barely used (they serve websites that are rarely used).

I also had an application that was used 24/7 and used up all my free tier hours. I've bumped that to a [Hobby](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#containers) [dyno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku#Architecture) by now, but now all of my free tier applications aren't working.

Can I purchase some more free tier hours? Otherwise, the only way to make all of those sites that are rarely used to work is to make them all hobby, which isn't worth my money.

Comment: This seems like a great question for Heroku support, and a very off-topic question for StackOverflow. Also, won't this resolve itself next month?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be directed to Heroku support.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I've sent this to support already, waiting to hear back. What's changing in a month?

Comment: In a month your free hours reset and since you've upgraded the greedy/busy app to Hobby it won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You cannot buy free tier hours. Your Heroku account has a total amount of 'free hours' per month, and if you use them all up they are gone.

You can upgrade *just* the applications you care about to the *Hobby* plan.

Comment: Hey Randall Degges, nice to see you bro! Yeah, a little tough for me since a lot of those sites have very little requests but thanks for the answer.